# Lazy shared async resource — Clarification?

Tags: c#, async-await

I saw this example at the end of Stephen's book.

This code can be accessed by *more* than one thread.

```
static int _simpleValue;
static readonly Lazy<Task<int>> MySharedAsyncInteger = new Lazy<Task<int>>(  
async () =>
{
   await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)).ConfigureAwait(false);
   return _simpleValue++;
});

async Task GetSharedIntegerAsync()
{
    int sharedValue = await MySharedAsyncInteger.Value;
}
```

No matter how many parts of the code call Value simultaneously, the
`Task<int>` is only created *once* and returned to all callers.

But then he says :

> If there are different thread types that may call `Value` (e.g., a UI
>   thread and a thread-pool thread, or two different ASP.NET request
>   threads), then it may be better to always execute the asynchronous
>   delegate on a thread-pool thread.

So he suggests the following code which makes the whole code run in a threadpool thread :

```
static readonly Lazy<Task<int>> MySharedAsyncInteger = new Lazy<Task<int>>(() => Task.Run(
async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
    return _simpleValue++;;
}));
```

**Question:**

I don't understand what's the problem with the *first* code. The continuation  would be executed in a threadpool thread (due to ConfigureAwait ,  we don't need the original context).

Also as soon that any control from any thread will reach the `await` , the control will be back to the caller.

I don't see what  *extra* risk the second code is trying to resolve.

I mean - what is the problem with "*different thread types that may call `Value`*" in the *first* code?

Comment: *The continuation would be executed in a threadpool thread* I can't believe that is guaranteed by the contract of that method. At best it is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> what is the problem with "different thread types that may call Value"
>   in the first code?

There in nothing *wrong* with that code. But, imagine you had some CPU bound work along with the `async` initialization call. Picture it like this for example:

```
static readonly Lazy<Task<int>> MySharedAsyncInteger = new Lazy<Task<int>>(
async () =>
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 5)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        i++;
    }

    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
    return 0;
});
```

Now, you aren't "guarded" against these kind of operations. I'm assuming Stephan mentioned the UI thread because you shouldn't be doing any operation that's longer than 50ms on it. You don't want your UI thread to freeze, ever.

When you use `Task.Run` to invoke the delegate, you're covering yourself from places where one might pass a long running delegate to your `Lazy<T>`.

Stephan Toub talks about this in [*AsyncLazy*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/15/asynclazy-lt-t-gt.aspx):

> Here we have a new `AsyncLazy<T>` that derives from `Lazy<Task<T>>` and
>   provides two constructors.  Each of the constructors takes a function
>   from the caller, just as does `Lazy<T>`.  The first constructor, in
>   fact, takes the same Func that `Lazy<T>`.  Instead of passing that
>   `Func<T>` directly down to the base constructor, however, we instead
>   pass down a new `Func<Task<T>>` which simply uses StartNew to run the
>   user-provided `Func<T>`.  The second constructor is a bit more fancy. 
>   Rather than taking a `Func<T>`, it takes a `Func<Task<T>>`.  With this
>   function, we have two good options for how to deal with it.  The first
>   is simply to pass the function straight down to the base constructor,
>   e.g:

```
public AsyncLazy(Func<Task<T>> taskFactory) : base(taskFactory) { }
```

> That option works, but it means that when a user accesses the Value
>   property of this instance, the taskFactory delegate will be invoked
>   synchronously.  That could be perfectly reasonable if the `taskFactory`
>   delegate does very little work before returning the task instance. 
>   **If, however, the `taskFactory` delegate does any non-negligable work, a
>   call to Value would block until the call to `taskFactory` completes.  To
>   cover that case, the second approach is to run the `taskFactory` using
>   `Task.Factory.StartNew`, i.e. to run the delegate itself asynchronously,
>   just as with the first constructor, even though this delegate already
>   returns a `Task<T>`.**