# Cache expensive object for thread-scope using DI, without blocking (async)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-core

I've got an expensive "current user" obejct that I want to cache for the duration of the request. To do this I'm using the built-in DI in asp.net core, to create a `ICurrentUser` object when requested. It looks like this:

```
public class CurrentUserCache : ICurrentUser
{
    public CurrentUserCache(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, UserManager userManager)
    {
        var httpContextAccessor1 = httpContextAccessor;
        _user = new Lazy<User>(() => httpContextAccessor1.HttpContext.User != null ? userManager.GetUserAsync(httpContextAccessor1.HttpContext.User).Result : null);
    }

    private Lazy<User> _user;
    public User User {
        get => _user.Value;
        set {}
    }

}
```

It's using a `Lazy` object to defer the retrieval of the object, since some controller actions might not need to make use of it.

My problem is - the code inside the lazy to get the user, is blocking (`.Result`). I don't want to do that, since it's quite expensive.

I don't know how to make this code async. I could possibly create a `Lazy<Task<user>>` to get the user, but then I can't `await` that in my user property, because it's a property and properties can't be async.

So - how can I turn this code into something that works well for async?

Thanks!

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32679483/lazy-shared-async-resource-clarification help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn the property into an awaitable function

```
public class CurrentUserCache : ICurrentUser {
    public CurrentUserCache(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, UserManager userManager) {
        _user = new Lazy<Task<User>>(() => 
            userManager.GetUserAsync(httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User)
        );
    }

    private Lazy<Task<User>> _user;

    public Task<User> GetUserAsync() {
        return _user.Value;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it does look like this is the best option - I'd have liked to keep it a property for aesthetic reasons but this works